# Регулярка с заменой подстрок из массива

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Например есть строка

```
var str = "В городе %s, живет %s людей";
```

Так вызываем функцию

```
var res = print(str,'X', 99999999); //res = "В городе X, живет 99999999 людей"
```

Далее внутри `print()` мы получим arguments, и нам нужна будет регулярка, которая по порядку заменит все `%s` на значения из массива, так же если кол-во `%s` превышает кол-во элементов массива значения для подстановки то такие `%s` не будут заменены, а если наоборот - то лишние значения будут проигнорены.
Как правильно написать такую функцию `print()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var s = "В городе %s, живет %s людей";

function printf(str) {
  // Получаем все аргументы для подстановки
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  // Генератор функции-подстановки
  var subst = function(a) {
    // Функция, которая будет выдавать очередную подстроку для String.replace()
    return function() {
      return a.length > 0 ? a.shift() : "%s";
    };
  };
  return str.replace(/%s/g, subst(args));
}

alert("before: [ " + s + " ],\nafter: [ " + printf(s, "N", 999) + " ]");

// Тест с недостатком аргументов
s += " %s ...";
alert("before: [ " + s + " ],\nafter: [ " + printf(s, "N", 999) + " ]");
```